# Android video color adjustments

Tags: android, video, colors, ffmpeg, colorfilter

I'm working on an Android app that among other things will allow the users to make short videos, apply funny effects to them and share them with one another. To begin with, i'm looking for simple color-effects like grayscale, brightness, contrast, sepiatoning, and such.

All this would be very simple by using the camera-class which can apply the color effects at recording-time - at least most phone's cameras can - i've tested some using `Camera.getParameters().getSupportedColorEffects();`. But the thing is: **i need to do it after the recording has been done**: the user would open a video, and choose among a set of effects to apply; then upload that changed video to a shared server.

I can't for the love of *** find a good way to do this.

Android doesn't seem to include any videoutilities in the sdk. The `android.media.effect package` can do some effects, but only backdropper for videos, the rest are for images. Extracting bitmaps from the surfaceview of a videoview during playback doesn't work, it just returns an all-black bitmap. It seems like there's no way to intercept the datastream between the storage and the screen. and apply the effects there. I've started to look into using the FFmpeg library to decode a video file so i can get access to the data, but that requires quite a bit of native coding, and also requires separate compiles for various CPU architectures, so it's very messy. I thought that as the camera can apply these effects *(on a Sony LT26i: none, mono, negative, solarize, sepia, posterize)*, perhaps one could feed the recorder with a videostream not from the camera, but from the memory, and by that way use a stored video file?

Do anyone know if there is a good way to apply effects to a video - **after** it has been recorded?

Comment: Thanks Dear you solved my problem. I was required to put effects during recording. :)

Comment: I am still looking for the answer of this question, @Christian. Let me know if you know how you did it

Comment: It's a loong time ago, I ended up using ffmpeg library to decode the videos into individual images, apply an effect (color-adjustments and overlay), and then encode them back into a video.
The result was far from super, and it took forever to apply those filters.

Comment: can you share code? i have same issue. please !